# Submit Record Edit Form for every object in Aura iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, aura-iteration, lightning-recordeditform

I have a Contact object form with a child form component for *Buying Center* objects.
When I *upsert* the Contact, I need to submit a list of *Buying Centers* for this Contact.

**Parent Contact component** has a child component with ID attribute:

```js
<c:buyingCenter masterRecordId="{!v.contact}" aura:id="buyingCentersComponent"/>
```

**Parent controller** calls *aura:methods* from child component upon *onclick* on a Save button:

```js
 upsertContact: function (component, event, helper) {
        try {
            component.find("buyingCentersComponent").initialSaveBuyingCentersAndCheckRequiredFields();
            component.find("buyingCentersComponent").saveBuyingCentersFromParent();
            helper.upsertContact(component, contact);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('There was an error: ' + e);
        }
    }
```

In **child Buying Center component** I have *recordEditForm* inside an *aura:iteration*:

```html
<aura:attribute name="buyingCenters" type="Buying_Center_Assignment__c[]" default="[]"/>

<aura:method name="initialSaveBuyingCentersAndCheckRequiredFields" action="{!c.initialSaveBuyingCentersAndCheckRequiredFields}" access="PUBLIC">
    <aura:attribute name="foundError" default="false" type="Boolean"/>
</aura:method>

<aura:method name="saveBuyingCentersFromParent" action="{!c.saveBuyingCentersFromParent}" access="PUBLIC"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.buyingCenters}" var="buyingCenter">
        <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
              <lightning:recordEditForm
                      aura:id="buyingCenterEditForm"
                      recordId="{!buyingCenter.Id}"
                      objectApiName="Buying_Center_Assignment__c">

                  <lightning:layout>
                      <lightning:layoutItem size="5">
                                  <lightning:inputField fieldName="Purchase_Unit__c"/>
                      </lightning:layoutItem>
                      <lightning:layoutItem size="5">
                                  <lightning:inputField fieldName="Role__c"/>
                      </lightning:layoutItem>
                  </lightning:layout>

              </lightning:recordEditForm>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
</aura:iteration>
```

Now this child component has a method to add Buying Center objects to view. After adding the object the user can select values using *recordEditForm*:

```js
addBuyingCenter: function (component, event, helper) {
       var buyingCenters = component.get("v.buyingCenters");
       if (buyingCenters == null) {
           buyingCenters = [];
       }
       var buyingCenter = {};
       buyingCenters.push(buyingCenter);
       component.set("v.buyingCenters", buyingCenters);
   }
```

When user finally clicks **Save** the list of *Buying Centers* is supposed to submit before the whole Contact form is also submitted:

```js
initialSaveBuyingCentersAndCheckRequiredFields: function (component, event, helper) {
        var foundCmp = component.find('buyingCenterEditForm');
        console.log('Component to submit: ' + foundCmp);
        for (var i = 0; i < foundCmp.length; i++) {
            foundCmp[i].submit(); 
        }

        //After submitting I try to get the records again to check if submit was successful
       var masterRecordId = component.get("v.masterRecordId");
       helper.loadBuyingCenters(component, event, helper, masterRecordId);

       //This should be assigned by the helper but it's empty
       var buyingCenters = component.get("v.buyingCenters");
       console.log('Buying centers after submit: ' + JSON.stringify(buyingCenters));

        //additional logic to validate required fields      
}
```

The problem is that the *Buying Centers* **are not submitting**. The logs currently show:

```
Component to submit: SecureComponentRef: markup://lightning:recordEditForm {427:0} {buyingCenterEditForm}{ key: {"namespace":"c"} } buyingCenter.js:100:17
Buying centers after submit: [{}]
```

The object is correctly added to the view, I can select fields in the Record Edit Form but they are not saving. Is there anything wrong with my logic?

Comment: can you add 'onsuccess` && `onerror` events to `lightning:erecordeditform` then see what errors are coming, it gives more error info.

Answer (score 0):

After adding `onError` handler to the `lightning:recordeditform` it turned out I was missing a field when submitting the records - I needed to add Id of parent that the child relates to and I achieved it with a hidden field:

```html
<lightning:layoutItem class="slds-hide">
    <!-- Hidden Contact ID field needed for submit -->
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Contact__c" value="{!v.masterRecord.Id}"/>
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

Lesson learned - use `onError`, `onSubmit` and `onSuccess` handlers to check your *recordEditForm*